# Matplotlib clustered box and whisker plot with multiple series

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a box and whisker plot like my drawing below where each colour represents a measurement station.  Each bar will be derived from an individual array.  I've included an image of what my current plot looks like.

Currently all my data is in individual arrays, but I can reformat it if necessary.  I am currently making the plots using the code shown below, but am fine with changing that as well.

Thanks!

[image: What I'd ideally like]
[image: What I have now]

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols =3, figsize=[10,10])

ax[0,0].boxplot(T_MAE, whis = 1.5, sym='')
ax[1,0].boxplot(T_CORR, whis =1.5, sym='')

ax[0,1].boxplot(WS_MAE, whis = 1.5, sym='')
ax[1,1].boxplot(WS_CORR, whis =1.5, sym='')

ax[0,2].boxplot(WD_RMSE, whis = 1.5, sym='')
ax[1,2].boxplot(WD_CORR, whis =1.5, sym='')

f.set_facecolor('white')
plt.show()
```

Comment: what is the problem with your current output? Have you tried anything to make it closer to your desired output?
What is the structure of your arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around 'cause I was interested to figure this kind of graphs out for myself.

I generated some data like so:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# generate some bogus data
a = ['Temp', 'WS', 'WD']
b = ['Error','Correlation']
c = ['ST1', 'ST2', 'ST3'] * 10
d = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a, b, c], names=['measurement', 'type', 'station'])
e = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.random.random_sample((180,))}, index=d)
f = e.reset_index()
```

which creates a pandas DataFrame like so. Each row/value is associated with whichever Station, kind of measurement, etc to which it corresponds

```
    measurement type    station value
0   Temp    Error   ST1 0.147856
1   Temp    Error   ST2 0.775522
2   Temp    Error   ST3 0.219525
3   Temp    Error   ST1 0.781051
4   Temp    Error   ST2 0.611896
5   Temp    Error   ST3 0.548077
6   Temp    Error   ST1 0.155149
7   Temp    Error   ST2 0.512718
8   Temp    Error   ST3 0.678058
(...)
172 WD  Correlation ST2 0.412141
173 WD  Correlation ST3 0.431907
174 WD  Correlation ST1 0.635392
175 WD  Correlation ST2 0.623895
176 WD  Correlation ST3 0.520754
177 WD  Correlation ST1 0.773108
178 WD  Correlation ST2 0.635676
179 WD  Correlation ST3 0.142240
```

then I plotted it using a FacetGrid. I had to play around with the settings to get an output that's close to what you drew up.

```
sns.set_style("white")
g = sns.FacetGrid(f, col="measurement", row="type",
                 sharey=True, sharex=True)
g.map(sns.boxplot, "station", "value", palette=['r', 'g', 'b'])

(
g.set_axis_labels("", "val")
 .set_titles("{col_name}")
 .despine(bottom=True, left=True)
)


g.axes[0,0].set_ylabel("Error")
g.axes[1,0].set_ylabel("Correlation")

for h in g.axes[1,:]:
    h.set_title('')
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great!  Can you tell me a little about the 'seaborn' module you used?  I've used the rest but never come across this one.

Comment: Seaborn is a library for making attractive and informative statistical graphics in Python. It is built on top of matplotlib. It has lots of built-in functions to generate this kind of graphs, where you want to group your data by different criteria, or to explore the distributions and the correlations in your data. Read more http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/index.html